# Access Lookup to Linked List

Tags: 2010, lookup-column, access, links-list

I am trying to create a lookup from one Access table to a linked list from SharePoint.  I need to have a lookup between the two because in order to create the type of subform that I need, there has to be a relationship between the two tables.  However, the 'Relationships' button on the ribbon in Access is greyed out, and I'm not sure why.  It seems to me that I have done what has been suggested in the blogs that I have found, but I'm having no luck.  It may or may not be significant that there is an error every time I open the linked list (no idea why) claiming that 'The setting you entered isn't valid for this property.'  That one confuses me a bit, as I haven't actually set any properties- it comes up just from opening the list to view.  I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it, but I haven't yet found a solution.  Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**  As an added bonus, whenever I try to refresh the list, I get a table named 'Name AutoCorrect Save Failures' containing the message 'Could not save the object'.

Answer (score 0):

I might try repair/compacting the Access db if you haven't already.

What happens if you connect SharePoint to a table in a different Access db - do you get the same errors? If not, it may be a problem with the specific Access table.

Comment: No luck on the repair.  As for trying another DB, I haven't done this yet, but I do have another table from the same SharePoint site linked to the same DB, and that one has no error.  However, as the original problem still stands, I can't create a lookup to that one either.